# Can て form nominalize verbs?

Tags: grammar, usage, て-form

> お母さん、風香産んで正解だった。

This sentence means "Mother was right about giving birth to Fuuka." but I don't understand the usage of the て form here. I think it nominalized the verb but isn't this the job of こと or の ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You probably know "食べていい?" is parsed like "Eat and okay?" but means "Can I eat it?". Saying いい last may not seem natural at first sight, but this is a natural word order in Japanese. You are seeing a similar structure here. This te-form is not technically a nominalizer but just "and". You can read it like "I gave birth to Fuka and made a right decision (by doing it)". But using a nominalizer and saying お母さん(が)風香(を)産んだ**の**(は)正解だったわ makes sense, too.

Comment: oh okay, thanks very much for clarifying